# Combining Multiple Binary Classifiers (LinearSVC) for Multilabel Classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset with 6 classes that can be mapped to 4 one-hot-encoded columns so that each class corresponds to a distinct combination of one-hot-encodings:

|  | Class | one-hot1 | one-hot2 | one-hot3 | one-hot4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | class1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | class2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | class3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | class4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | class5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | class6 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I was able to fit 4 different binary classifiers that all performed fairly well (~90% accuracy with little bias) on each one-hot-encoded column. How can I combine these 4 classifiers into one classifier without fitting each classifier on irrelevant data?

An example of one of the binary classifiers:

```
# Optimized ngrams + features
transformer_one_hot_1 = FeatureUnion([
                ('feature1_tfidf', 
                  Pipeline([('extract_field',
                              FunctionTransformer(return_feature1, validate=False)),
                            ('tfidf', 
                              TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 6), analyzer='char_wb', sublinear_tf=True, lowercase=False))])),
                ('feature2_tfidf', 
                  Pipeline([('extract_field', 
                              FunctionTransformer(return_feature2, validate=False)),
                            ('tfidf', 
                              TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 7), analyzer='char_wb', sublinear_tf=True, lowercase=False))])),
                ('feature3_tfidf', 
                  Pipeline([('extract_field', 
                              FunctionTransformer(return_feature3, validate=False)),
                            ('tfidf', 
                              TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 6), analyzer='char_wb', sublinear_tf=True, lowercase=False))])),
                ('feature4_tfidf', 
                  Pipeline([('extract_field', 
                              FunctionTransformer(return_feature4, validate=False)),
                            ('tfidf', 
                              TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 8), analyzer='char_wb', sublinear_tf=True, lowercase=False))]))]) 


# Pipeline
pipeline_one_hot_1 = Pipeline(
        [
        ("tfidfs", transformer_one_hot_1),
        ("classifier", LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced')),
        ]
        )

# Fit the pipeline to the one-hot-encoded column of interest
pipeline_one_hot_1.fit(X_train, y_train['one-hot1'])
```

Each classifier (`pipeline_one_hot_1`, `pipeline_one_hot_2`, `pipeline_one_hot_3`, etc) performs fairly well on their own.

Right now I combine the outputs of the separately trained binary classifiers to generate the predicted one-hot-encoded columns:

```
one-hot-col-1 = pipeline_one_hot_1.predict(X_test)
one-hot-col-2 = pipeline_one_hot_2.predict(X_test)
one-hot-col-3 = pipeline_one_hot_3.predict(X_test)
one-hot-col-4 = pipeline_one_hot_4.predict(X_test)
```

I then check those outputs to see if they correspond to the one-hot-encodings for each class. 
However, what I'd like to have ultimately is a classifier that takes in the dataframe/dictionary and returns the one-hot-encoded vector:

```
prediction = combined_classifiers.predict(X_test)
```

where `prediction` is an array with shape `(nsamples, n-onehotencodedcolumns)`.

Specifically, how can I ensure that each of the classifiers is only trained on relevant data? I.e. I don't want to train `pipeline_one_hot_1` on column `one-hot2`. Is there a way to ensure a classifier in a `StackingClassifier()` only sees certain data when being fit so that the finely tuned models don't get fitted to the wrong one-hot-encoded column?

Comment: It's very rare that people bother reading and understanding that much information. I would strongly advice you to keep just the information needed for your question

Comment: Yah this was my feeling as well. I'll rework it to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

To answer strictly your question: you can simply concatenate the predicted boolean values and decode the full one-hot vector. Then you can evaluate the predicted classes against the true classes.

However this is unlikely to work very well, unless you have some expert knowledge which justifies that the classes should be divided this way (for example if there is some hierarchical ordering between the classes).

In general the class label doesn't have to be one-hot encoded, as opposed to categorical features. The categorical nature of the label can safely be represented as a numeric value, typically with [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). In brief: this is because the model does not and cannot use the numerical order of the label, whereas in the case of a categorical feature represented as a number it would wrongly rely on the order.

Comment: I do have expert knowledge, so that is feasible. Mainly what I'd like to do is combine the classifiers that were trained on the one-hot-encoded columns and then use their combined outputs as inputs for another classifier which predicts the class label.

Comment: If you look at the first version of my question (in the edits) there's more details on the specifics of my problem. Basically stacking is suboptimal because the LinearSVCs of each binary classifier will be trained as one-vs-rest for each class label which reduces performance because each class depends on different features and/or hyperparameters.

Comment: Ok I see, you started with real OHT (6 variables) but now it's not OHT anymore, it's a dataset-specific representation. So assuming you have good reasons to train independent classifiers this way, it is more or less multilabel classification indeed. However I don't see how training a meta-classifier on the predicted boolean variables would help: if the booleans are correctly predicted then there's only one possible class. In cases of errors (an impossible combination of booleans) it would probably default to the most likely class anyway. Both can be done deterministically.

Comment: In the end I ended up writing my own custom classifier. I stacked the confidence intervals from each individual model into a vector and used another classifier on that vector to predict the class integer (1-6). The accuracy was 87% for my model vs 89% for the StackingClassifier() although when exported, my custom classifier was 1/10th the size. The 2% difference wasn't enough to justify the inflated model size and my custom classifier is more straightforward to interpret.